# Express route with optional parameter?

Tags: express, routes

I have an Express route for `public-sitemap.xml`:

```
app.get("/public-sitemap.xml", function(req, res) {
    // do stuff
});
```

I'd like to support URLs like `public-sitemap-1.xml`, `public-sitemap-2.xml` as well.

How can I allow these optional parameters in Express?

If I set the route to `/public-sitemap-?:id?.xml` that allows `public-sitemap-1.xml` etc, but it also allows `public-sitemap1.xml`, which I'd prefer to reject.

Comment: You can use a regex in a route definition.  That's probably what you would do here.  A bunch of examples here: https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
/public-sitemap(-:id?)?.xml
```

More info here: https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html

Comment: Yes, that's it exactly! Thanks.

Comment: No problem! Good luck!

Answer (score -1):

Use this:

```
app.get("/public-sitemap-:id(\\d+).xml", function(req, res) {
    // do stuff
});
```